# JQuery Issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm using JQuery in a Wordpress site (Thesis theme) to dynamically swap images. Everything works as expected in Chrome/Firefox/Safari, but the images don't show up at all in IE. Where have I gone wrong? Code below, dev site at [daf.drivechannelcreative.com/about](http://daf.drivechannelcreative.com/about).

```
    function add_image_header(){
    global $post;

    $image_header = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_header', true );
    $image_one_full = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_one_full', true );
    $image_one_cropped = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_one_cropped', true );
    $image_two_full = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_two_full', true );
    $image_two_cropped = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_two_cropped', true );
    $image_three_full = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_three_full', true );
    $image_three_cropped = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_three_cropped', true );

    $page_meta_desc = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'thesis_description', true );

    if($image_header){
        ?>  
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".thumb").click(function(){
                   var Image1Main = $(this).data('main');
                   var Image1Thumb = $(this).attr('src');

                   var Image2Main = $('#main_image').attr('src');
                   var Image2Thumb = $('#main_image').data('thumb');

                   $('#main_image').attr("src", Image1Main);
                   $('#main_image').data("thumb", Image1Thumb);


                   $(this).attr("src", Image2Thumb);
                   $(this).data("main", Image2Main);
                });
            });
            </script>

            <div id="img_header_container">
                <img data-thumb="<?php echo $image_one_cropped;?>" src="<?php echo $image_one_full;?>" id="main_image"/>
                <img class="thumb" data-main="<?php echo $image_two_full;?>" src="<?php echo $image_two_cropped;?>"/>
                <div id="heading_text"><h2><?php echo get_the_title($ID) ?></h2><?php echo $page_meta_desc;?></div>
                <img class="thumb thumb_two" data-main="<?php echo $image_three_full;?>" src="<?php echo $image_three_cropped;?>"/>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('thesis_hook_before_post_box', 'add_image_header');
```

Comment: They don't show up for me even in Chrome.

Comment: Look at the rendered HTML. Missing images point to a domain that doesn't exist... http://daf.dev/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/image_two_crop_example1.jpg

Comment: 404 errors don't have anything to do with how you've programmed it.

Comment: Yep, when I moved the site to a new server I lost the link. It's always the easy thing. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what a piece of your generated HTML looks like:

```
<img class="thumb" data-main="http://daf.dev/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/image_two_full_example1.jpg" src="http://daf.dev/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/image_two_crop_example1.jpg"/>
```

The value in the `data-main` attribute is not a working image URL and that's one of the values that you're going to set the `.src` value to for your image tag.  Somehow, I don't think you're generating the right URLs or the images are present at those URLs or this webpage doesn't work for outsiders like us (I'm not sure which).

Answer (score 1):

To set the "src" attribute with jQuery since 1.6, you need to use ".prop()", not ".attr()":

```
               $(this).prop("src", Image2Thumb);
```

Seems like a simple thing but it makes a difference now.

Using ".attr()" with just one argument to *get* the value is *possibly* OK but even then you're better off with ".prop()".

*edit* — Brad Christie correctly points out that simply:

```
               this.src = Image2Thumb;
```

woks great when your jQuery object is just a single element (like in the code above).  The jQuery form is useful if you're setting a zillion different elements.

Comment: Personally, I prefer using `this.src` given it's going to be a DOM image anyways, but that may be preference.